# Call c function from Julia under windows. MinGW vs MSBuild

Tags: interface, msbuild, julia, mingw

Trying to figure out why a simple c function compiled with MinGW can be called without problems within Julia, but the same compiled with MSBuild (12.0) won't work. Im using Julia 64bit and I checked that the c function compiled both ways is a 64 bit dll. I use cmake to create the make file

the Julia code:

```
println("hello world")
t = ccall((:giveMin, "C:\\MyProjects\\Julia-Tests\\some-c-lib\\build-mingw\\src\\libgetMinimum.dll"), Int32, ())
print(t)
```

The c code:

```
int givemin(void);
int giveMin(void){
int minval = 0; 
return minval; 
}
```

As said before. The Julia code will work only with the MinGW generated dll, but in the other case the following error will be prompted:

ccall: could not find function giveMin in library

Comment: have you tried to use `extern "C" {}` to mute C++'s name mangling?

Comment: I did after your comment, but it does not work because im compiling a c program. no c program will understand `extern "C" {}`. At least this way I know the MSBuild is understanding the code as c code and not c++.

Comment: does `__declspec(dllexport)` help?

Comment: you may also need to use dependencywalker to check out what mangling rule is being used by MSVC.

Comment: I have been playing around with dependencywalker to try to track the differences between the dlls. will report if I do found something